# How can i send my inputvalue of <TextInput> to a async function through a onSubmitEditing?

Tags: react-native

I want to save the value of the input of a field in react native. How can I send the value to an async function by using the `onSubmitediting` event?

I tried this:

```
<TextInput onSubmitEditing={ (text) => this.Store(text)}></TextInput>
```

and this is the function I'm using

```
Store = async() =>
{
    var textvalue = "here the value of the <TextInput>";
    try 
    {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Temp:city', textvalue );
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: change your Store function like this:
`Store = async(textvalue) =>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
   <TextInput 
     onSubmitEditing={ event => {
      const text = event.nativeEvent.text;
      this.Store(text);
    }} >
   </TextInput>
```

And save like this:

```
Store = async(text) => {
     try 
     {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('@Temp:city', text );

     } 
     catch (error) 
     {
      console.log(error)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Seems a good option. but you cant do  it like i said at my question ?